# RABL child method gives wrong name for array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

If I have the following in a RABL template:

```
object @user

child :followed_users do
  # ...
end
```

I would expect the JSON output to look like this: (I have `include_json_root` and `include_child_root` disabled.)

```
{
  "followed_users": [
    // ...
  ]
}
```

However, for some reason it looks like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    // ...
  ]
}
```

I discovered I can make it work by replacing `child :followed_users do` with `child :followed_users => :followed_users do`, but I think that that's probably the wrong way to go about this.

What should I be doing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem - find a fix?

Comment: @PaulOsetinsky Nope. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with RABL but it seems similar to other libraries. I'd try two things:

- First, see if RABL is actually removing `followed_` from `followed_users` by confirming that `whatever_something` behaves the exact same way. I'm uncertain if `users` has special meaning (or conflicting configuration) somewhere else in your code since I see `object @users`.
- Try using a string instead of a symbol for the key (`"followed_users"`). Some libraries treat symbols and strings differently.